# How to find the distance between 2 points in 2 different dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've got two dataframes, each with a set of coordinates. `Dataframe 1` is a list of biomass sites, with coordinates in columns 'lat' and 'lng'. `Dataframe 2` is a list of postcode coordinates, linked to sale price, with coordinates in columns 'pc_lat' and 'pc_lng'.

I've used [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843122/how-to-find-the-closest-match-based-on-2-keys-from-one-dataframe-to-another) to work out the closest biomass site to each property. This is the code I am using:

```
def dist(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
return np.abs((lat1-lat2)+(long1-long2))

def find_site(lat, long):
    distances = biomass.apply(
        lambda row: dist(lat, long, row['lat'], row['lng']), 
        axis=1)
    return biomass.loc[distances.idxmin(),'Site Name']

hp1995['BiomassSite'] = hp1995.apply(
    lambda row: find_site(row['pc_lat'], row['pc_long']), 
    axis=1)

print(hp1995.head())
```

This has worked well, in that I've got the name of the closest Biomass generation site, however I want to know the distance calculated between these two sites.

1. How would I calculate the distance?
2. What metric would the output distance be in? I am trying to find properties within 2km from the biomass site.

Comment: you may want to check [a __vectorized__ haversine function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45054507/5741205)

Comment: Hmm will have a look. How much quicker is it?

Comment: IMO it's worth to compare the timing - i would expect it to be __much__ faster

Comment: Okay, will have a play around with that. Problem is that I've run the other function for most of my data, so changing at this point my be inconsistent when looked at later on

Answer (score 3):

To calculate distance between two global coordinates you should use the [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), based on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) page I have implemented the following method:

```
import math
def distanceBetweenCm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    dLat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dLon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)

    lat1 = math.radians(lat1)
    lat2 = math.radians(lat2)

    a = math.sin(dLat/2) * math.sin(dLat/2) + math.sin(dLon/2) * math.sin(dLon/2) * math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    return c * 6371 * 100000 #multiply by 100k to get distance in cm
```

You can also modify it  to return different units, by multiplying by different powers of 10. In the example a multiplication by 100k results in units in centimeters. Without multiplying the method returns distance in km. From there you could perform more unit conversions if necessary .

Edit: As suggested in the comments, one possible optimization for this would be using power operators instead of regular multiplication, like this:

```
a = math.sin(dLat/2)**2 + math.sin(dLon/2)**2 * math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2)
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019740/speed-of-calculating-powers-in-python) question to read more about different speed complexities of calculating powers in python.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your question you should consider accepting this answer so it is useful for future users with similar questions.

Comment: Full points for knowing haversines. I think you could improve the efficiency by using `a = math.sin(dLat/2)**2 + math.sin(dLon/2)**2 * math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2)`

Comment: @ShawnMehan great suggestion, will edit to add it to the answer

Comment: Just one more thing - to get distance in kilometres, I need to multiply it by 20000000000 (100000 * 200000). One example result is '8.441422e+11'

Comment: What does that value mean?

Comment: Okay, i've just realised that I've flipped this notation completely.

Comment: @CTaylor19 to obtain units in Km you should just do `return c * 6371` (as indicated in the answer), that is no multiplication by powers of 10. When multiplying by 100k, as in the example code, you obtain distance in centimeters.

Comment: OK, got it! Thanks

Comment: No problem, good luck with your coding. If you found this answer solved your question remember to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it so it helps future users.